# Best practices to delete a set of tables in sql 2008

Tags: sql-server, transactions

Basically I want to keep the transaction very simple but I should be able to rollback if any error occurs in the later part.
Something like:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

  DELETE SET 1(this will delete first set of table)
  COMMIT

  DELETE SET 2 (will delete second set of table)
```

If any error occurs while deleting set 2 I should be able to rollback set 1 transaction as well. Let me know if we have any options to do like this. Appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 2):

> If any error occurs while deleting set
>   2 i should be able to rollback set 1
>   transaction as well.Let me know if we
>   have any options to do like this.
>   Appreciate for your help.

Then, why don't you do this?

```
BEGIN TRY
   BEGIN TRANSACTION    -- Start the transaction

   DELETE SET 1(this will delete first set of table)
   DELETE SET 2 (will delete second set of table)

   -- If we reach here, success!
   COMMIT
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
  -- Whoops, there was an error
  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
     ROLLBACK

  -- Raise an error with the details of the exception
  DECLARE @ErrMsg nvarchar(4000), @ErrSeverity int
  SELECT @ErrMsg = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
         @ErrSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY()

  RAISERROR(@ErrMsg, @ErrSeverity, 1)
END CATCH
```

Read [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020150034/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/041906-1.shtml) for a complete explanation.

Answer (score -2):

If you mean deleting tables as in DELETE TABLE (I.e. the table, not the content), you are out of luck - DDL is not transacted.

Comment: DDL (DROP/CREATE) *is* transaction safe... if you've ever used Red-Gate SQL Compare you'll see it